# How to solve unsatisfiedlinkerror in android with ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Hi I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

Im not sure how to fix this error.- couldn't load cpudetect from loader.

Thanks

```
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922): FATAL EXCEPTION: EmulatorThread
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922): Process: com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid, PID: 8922
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cpudetect from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid-1]: findLibrary returned null
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922):     at com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid.DeSmuME.load(DeSmuME.java:40)
06-17 11:49:47.322: E/AndroidRuntime(8922):     at com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid.EmulatorThread.run(EmulatorThread.java:103)
06-17 11:49:47.893: E/ViewSystem(8922): ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid.
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Your image is unclear to see the error output, could you post the error message as text?

Comment: just reposted error message as text. thanks

Comment: The error log reported that your library `cpudetect` couldn't be found to load. Have you built into your library?